# boto3 get available actions per service

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I want to programatically get all the actions a user is allowed to do across aws services.
I've tried to fiddle with simulate_principal_policy but it seems this method expects a list of all actions, and I don't want to maintain a hard-coded list.

I also tried to call it with iam:* for example and got a generic 'implicitDeny' response so I know the user is not permitted all the actions but I require a higher granularity of actions.

Any ideas as to how do I get the action list dynamically?
Thanks!

Comment: _WHY_ do you wish to obtain this list?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, why is it your business? If you don't have the knowledge to share don't bother leaving non-helpful comments.

Comment: An IAM user can have: 1. inline policies, 2. managed policies and 3. IAM groups attached to it. You need to invoke a bunch of APIs to get all the info. Some of the APIs are: `get_user_policy`, `list_groups_for_user` (lists groups attached to user) and `list_attached_user_policies` (lists managed policies attached to user). From these, you need to invoke the respective APIs to get the permissions attached to them.

Comment: @Idanski I ask the question because, quite commonly, people ask how to accomplish a particular task in order to accomplish an unstated "ultimate goal", whereas there can be other (better) ways of accomplishing the "ultimate goal". Understanding the ultimate goal means that we can provide more-suitable answers to help you achieve your goal. For example, somebody might ask how to use CloudWatch to terminate an EC2 instance when they should really be using Auto Scaling. Knowing their goal lets us recommend a better course of action. See: [5 Whys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5_Whys)

Comment: I didn't leave the second comment.
All I can say is that my end goal for this is having a list of all available actions for a given service without me having to maintain it manually in case new actions are introduced by 
Amazon. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I am surprised no one has answered this question correctly. Here is code that uses `boto3` that addresses the OP's question directly:

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session('us-east-1')

for service in session.get_available_services ():
   service_client = session.client (service)
   print (service)
   print (service_client.meta.service_model.operation_names)
```

IAM, however, is a special case as it won't be listed in the `get_available_services()` call above:

```
IAM = session.client ('iam')
print ('iam')
print (IAM.meta.service_model.operation_names)
```

Comment: I don't see PassRole in Iam's operation_names

Answer (score 0):

To start with, there is **no programmatic way to retrieve all possible actions** (regardless of whether they are permitted to use an action).

You would need to construct a list of possible actions before checking the security. As an example, the `boto3` SDK for Python contains an internal list of commands that it uses to validate commands before sending them to AWS.

Once you have a particular action, you could use [Access the Policy Simulator API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_iam_policy-sim.html) to validate whether a given user would be allowed to make a particular API call. This is much easier than attempting to parse the various `Allow` and `Deny` permissions associated with a given user.

However, a call might be denied based upon the **specific parameters of the call**. For example, a user might have permissions to terminate any Amazon EC2 instance that has a particular tag, but cannot terminate *all* instances. To correctly test this, an `InstanceId` would need to be provided to the simulation.

Also, permissions might be restricted by IP Address and even Time of Day. Thus, while a user would have permission to call an Action, where and when they do it will have an impact on whether the Action is permitted.

**Bottom line:** It ain't easy! AWS will validate permissions at the time of the call. Use the **Policy Simulator** to obtain similar validation results.

Comment: Thanks, I know about the policy simulator.
What interests me is how to maintain a list of possible actions.